# Why $\{\frac 1 z: z \in \mathbb C, |z| = 1\} = \{z : z \in \mathbb C, |z| = 1\}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to understand why $\{\frac 1 z: z \in \mathbb C, |z| = 1\} = \{z : z\in \mathbb C, |z| = 1\}$.

If we take $z = x + iy$, then:

$$\frac 1 z = \frac{1}{x + iy} \cdot \frac{x - iy}{x - iy} = \frac{x - iy}{x^2 + y^2} = x-iy \neq z$$

So why there is equality between the two sets?

Comment: The statement in the first line says that the two sets are equal. It does not claim that $z=1/z$ for each element in the set. Perhaps it becomes clearer if you write it as $$\{\frac 1 z: z \in \mathbb C, |z| = 1\} = \{w : w\in \mathbb C, |w| = 1\}$$

Comment: Perfect! I understand! Thank you very much

Comment: Both of those sets are the unit circle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to see it is by substituting $1/z$ for $z$:
$$S=\{1/z: z \in \mathbb C, |z| = 1\} = \{z: 1/z \in \mathbb C, |1/z| = 1\}$$
As the condition implies $z\neq0$, $1/z\in\Bbb C$ is the same as $z\in\Bbb C$ so that $S$ can be written as:
$$S= \{z: z \in \mathbb C, 1/|z| = 1\}$$
Because $1/|z|=1$ is equivalent to $|z|=1$ we get the 2nd representation
$$S=\{z: z \in \mathbb C, |z| = 1\}$$

---

The equality means that the unit circle $|z|=1$ is invariant under the mapping $f:z\mapsto \frac1z$. However, $f$ restricted to the unit circle is not the identity, and the invariance under $f$ only holds on the complete unit circle as a set.

Answer (score 1):

Another intuitive way to understand this is, $\{z:z\in\mathbb{C},|z|=1\}$ represents a unit circle. Take any point on the circle, such as $(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2)$, and transform it using $1/z$, then it becomes $(\sqrt{2}/2,-\sqrt{2}/2)$. With the symmetry of a circle it's still on the circle. The circle is turned up side down and remains the same.